# How to display string array values in alert popup in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have to display string array in javascript alert popup,that popup will display string index or Serial Number then Space after string array value then line break. then display same way of all values in that array string. my code was not working.

```
    function Test(Str)
    {
    for(var i = 1; i <= Str.length; i++) 
    alert("Str["+i+"]: "+Str[i],"/n");

    }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Submit" runat="server" Text="Submit" onclick="Submit_Click" />  
    </div>

    C#:

    protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] Str = new string[5];
            Str[0] = "string1";
            Str[1] = "string2";
            Str[2] = "string3";
            Str[3] = "string4";
            Str[4] = "string5";
            Submit.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:Test(Str);");
        }



i need dispaly in following way:

1: string1
2: string2
3: string3
4: string4
5: string5
```

javascript popup was not working. how can i do this..

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you running into trouble? What don't you understand?

Comment: Looks like you're calling `test2(Str)`, but the function is named `Test()` ?

Comment: what is `yourArr` doing there

Answer (score 1):

I don't see your `test2` function.
And I think that you copied this function some place and not modify it:

```
function Test(Str)
{
for(var i = 1; i <= Str.length; i++) 
alert("yourArr["+i+"]: "+yourArr[i],"/n");

}
```

If above function is what you use, then it has some errors:

- using yourArr[i] instead of Str[i]
- using , (befor "/n") instead of +
- using "/n" instead of "\n"
- alert each string instead of a pack of strings

Answer (score 0):

You need to serialize the **C# string array into a javascript array**.

**C# Code:**

```
    string[] Str = new string[5];
    Str[0] = "string1";
    Str[1] = "string2";
    Str[2] = "string3";
    Str[3] = "string4";
    Str[4] = "string5";
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string jsArray = js.Serialize(Str);
    Submit.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:Test(" + jsArray + ");");
```

Also, **Modify Javascript Function**:

```
    function Test(Str) {
        for (var i = 1; i <= Str.length; i++)
            alert("yourArr[" + i + "]: " + Str[i], "/n");
    }
```